# System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path ext4

Tags: c#, filesystems, ext4

I've browsed through the simmilar questions, but couldn't find the answer on mine.

The problem I'm facing is that I have a webservice running on the windows 2008 server. The service tries to access files, which are on the NAS. The user, under which the service runs has the read rights to the network share (NAS). I'm still getting the exception System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path, even though the files which are requested actually exist there.

I have never had a simmilar issue, even though the settings are always the same (web service running on the windows server trying to access the files on the NAS). Can the factor be that the file system on the NAS is ext4 now, and it's always been ext3? That the only one difference, that I'm aware of.
Is there anything special I would need to take care of, concerning the file system?

EDIT:

The path I'm trying to access looks like:

```
  \\NAS\master\finished\20120809AB14001530\data\structure.xml
```

And yes, I can access it from the RUN command

The way I'm trying to access the file, in a simplified way, looks like following:

```
   try
   {
         var lXmlDoc = new XmlDocument();
         lXmlDoc.Load(XmlFilePath);
   }
   catch(Exception ex)
   {
      //Some error handling here
   }
```

Where the XmlFilePath is in this case: "\NAS\master\finished\20120809AB14001530\data\structure.xml"
And just to make it clearer: this has been always like that and it worked. The only one difference, in the current settings (that I'm aware of) is that it's ext4 on the NAS instead of ext3, which has been always there.

Comment: can you add the literal path you are trying to acceed into the question ?

Comment: Are you able to access the path physically...like RUN Command ?

Comment: Yeah I don't have access to it either. Weird eh? Anyway can you show the lines of code where you access it please?

Comment: Is windows compatible with Ext4 yet? Do you have extents on or off on the NAS? What drivers are you employing both in Windows (run command which you say works) and via your service? Could it be related to OpLocks? If not using externs, can you mount as Ext3 on the Ext4 NAS and check that it still works then? I think it is likely to be setting/driver related.